# Sharing a core data database between two instances of a table view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm making a shopping cart. In one tab, I have a table view controller with all the items. I have another tab, I have a shopping cart that has an 'add item to cart' button which segues to  another table view controller whose class I set the same as the table view controller of the items in the other tab.

But the problem is, the one from the segue does not load the rows anymore, so I get a blank cells. How do I fix this?

Does my question have anything to do with passing NSManagedObjects among objects?

Comment: You're going to have to show some code. Post the code of your "class i set the same as the table view controller" and also the code your using to "segue"

Comment: but it's going to be too long :( I'll try to get snippets. i'll be back.

Comment: Does my question have anything to do with passing NSManagedObjects among objects?

Comment: Not sure yet. It's quite possible. But without code, we may never know.

Comment: Hi @Vinnie, added my code snippets already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be very careful passing ManagedObjects between threads. `dispatch` call is likely to do so.  Instead, contain the processing to one thread per `ManagedObjectContext`.  I prefer using a specific worker thread that `main` calls which then dispatches the messages asynchronously to private methods.

This may or may not be the cause of your particular problem, but I've had significant issues with Core Data working across threads that are likely to at the very least pop up later for you.